# Issue with selecting a value in dropdown on IOS Safari Browser

Tags: dropdown

I'm unable to select value from dropdown on IOS SAFARI browser

Working On:

- IOS Device: IPhone 8,IPhone 8 Plus
- IOS Version : 11
- Selenium Version : 2.53.1
- Cloud : BrowserStack

We’ve tried to select the value from the dropdown using below workarounds but failed to succeed:
selectByValue , selectByVisibleText , selectByIndex , javascript select methods and Arrow up & down methods etc.

Html Code:

```html
<select class="ot_select success" data-rule-required="true" data-reactid=".1.2.0.$1.0.1.$0.1.2.0.2.$0.0.1.0.1.0">
   <option value="US" data-reactid=".1.2.0.$1.0.1.$0.1.2.0.2.$0.0.1.0.1.0.$0">United States</option>
   <option value="CA" data-reactid=".1.2.0.$1.0.1.$0.1.2.0.2.$0.0.1.0.1.0.$1">Canada</option>
   <option value="AF" data-reactid=".1.2.0.$1.0.1.$0.1.2.0.2.$0.0.1.0.1.0.$2">Afghanistan</option>
   <option value="AL" data-reactid=".1.2.0.$1.0.1.$0.1.2.0.2.$0.0.1.0.1.0.$3">Albania</option>
   <option value="DZ" data-reactid=".1.2.0.$1.0.1.$0.1.2.0.2.$0.0.1.0.1.0.$4">Algeria</option>
   <option value="AS" data-reactid=".1.2.0.$1.0.1.$0.1.2.0.2.$0.0.1.0.1.0.$5">American Samoa</option>
   <option value="AD" data-reactid=".1.2.0.$1.0.1.$0.1.2.0.2.$0.0.1.0.1.0.$6">Andorra</option>
</select>
```

Note:
When we use selectByValue, it doesn’t throw any error at the time of execution however corresponding action to that web element is not performed [leading to failure in dropdown value selection]

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and provide us with a proper example first of all.

Answer (score -1):

do JavaScript "document.getElementByClassName('ot_select success').value ='" & CA & "';" in document 1

Comment: hi,I have tried your code.Using this I was able to select the value but its corresponding action was not performed.Please share,if any solution is available